Building wheel for catboost error on macOS
I want to install catboost onto my mac machine, but I'm getting an error with build wheel. Here is my full error:
  Building wheels for collected packages: catboost
  Building wheel for catboost (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for catboost (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1

I read here that 1) installing ninja can help and 2) using a version of catboost <1.2 can also help. I tried both of these to no avail.

Hello, could you please give your python version and steps to reproduce the error? For example you can install catboost via pip on mac pip install catboost and this works fine.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

@JohnnyCheesecutter I'm using python 3.9.7. I do "pip install catboost" and I get this error. I have ARM architecture in my mac if that makes a difference. Is that the same with you?

I would definitely try to create new virtual env using 'pyenv' and install catboost into it. As for me, I have tried installing catboost in clean Python 3.9 environment and it works fine as well.
https://akrabat.com/creating-virtual-environments-with-pyenv/

Maybe you have a broken local cached catboost package or broken cache for one of it's dependencies. Try reinstalling it with pip without reusing local cache:  pip install --force-reinstall --no-cache-dir catboost


getting an error with build wheel.

The environment you're installing into is broken.
Discard it in favor of a new virtual environment.
The install works great.
This is on macOS Monterey 12.7.4, with python 3.12.2, to install
catboost-1.2.5.
Notice that we download a binary wheel,
with no local build tools needed.
$ pip -m venv venv
$ (source venv/bin/activate && python --version && time pip install catboost)
Python 3.12.2
Collecting catboost
  Using cached catboost-1.2.5-cp312-cp312-macosx_11_0_universal2.whl.metadata (1.2 kB)
Collecting graphviz (from catboost)
  Using cached graphviz-0.20.3-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (12 kB)
Collecting matplotlib (from catboost)
  Downloading matplotlib-3.8.4-cp312-cp312-macosx_10_12_x86_64.whl.metadata (5.8 kB)
Collecting numpy>=1.16.0 (from catboost)
  Using cached numpy-1.26.4-cp312-cp312-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl.metadata (61 kB)
Collecting pandas>=0.24 (from catboost)
  Downloading pandas-2.2.2-cp312-cp312-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl.metadata (19 kB)
Collecting scipy (from catboost)
  Downloading scipy-1.13.0-cp312-cp312-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl.metadata (60 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 60.6/60.6 kB 1.3 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting plotly (from catboost)
  Using cached plotly-5.21.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (7.1 kB)
Collecting six (from catboost)
  Using cached six-1.16.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.8 kB)
Collecting python-dateutil>=2.8.2 (from pandas>=0.24->catboost)
  Using cached python_dateutil-2.9.0.post0-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (8.4 kB)
Collecting pytz>=2020.1 (from pandas>=0.24->catboost)
  Using cached pytz-2024.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (22 kB)
Collecting tzdata>=2022.7 (from pandas>=0.24->catboost)
  Using cached tzdata-2024.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.4 kB)
Collecting contourpy>=1.0.1 (from matplotlib->catboost)
  Downloading contourpy-1.2.1-cp312-cp312-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl.metadata (5.8 kB)
Collecting cycler>=0.10 (from matplotlib->catboost)
  Using cached cycler-0.12.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.8 kB)
Collecting fonttools>=4.22.0 (from matplotlib->catboost)
  Downloading fonttools-4.51.0-cp312-cp312-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl.metadata (159 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 159.5/159.5 kB 3.5 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting kiwisolver>=1.3.1 (from matplotlib->catboost)
  Using cached kiwisolver-1.4.5-cp312-cp312-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl.metadata (6.4 kB)
Collecting packaging>=20.0 (from matplotlib->catboost)
  Using cached packaging-24.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.2 kB)
Collecting pillow>=8 (from matplotlib->catboost)
  Using cached pillow-10.3.0-cp312-cp312-macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl.metadata (9.2 kB)
Collecting pyparsing>=2.3.1 (from matplotlib->catboost)
  Using cached pyparsing-3.1.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (5.1 kB)
Collecting tenacity>=6.2.0 (from plotly->catboost)
  Using cached tenacity-8.2.3-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.0 kB)
Using cached catboost-1.2.5-cp312-cp312-macosx_11_0_universal2.whl (26.1 MB)
Using cached numpy-1.26.4-cp312-cp312-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (20.3 MB)
Downloading pandas-2.2.2-cp312-cp312-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (12.5 MB)
   ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 12.5/12.5 MB 3.8 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Using cached graphviz-0.20.3-py3-none-any.whl (47 kB)
Downloading matplotlib-3.8.4-cp312-cp312-macosx_10_12_x86_64.whl (7.6 MB)
   ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 7.6/7.6 MB 2.4 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Using cached plotly-5.21.0-py3-none-any.whl (15.7 MB)
Downloading scipy-1.13.0-cp312-cp312-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (39.4 MB)
   ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 39.4/39.4 MB 3.6 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Using cached six-1.16.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
Downloading contourpy-1.2.1-cp312-cp312-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (263 kB)
   ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 263.3/263.3 kB 4.4 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Using cached cycler-0.12.1-py3-none-any.whl (8.3 kB)
Downloading fonttools-4.51.0-cp312-cp312-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (2.3 MB)
   ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 2.3/2.3 MB 3.9 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Using cached kiwisolver-1.4.5-cp312-cp312-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (67 kB)
Using cached packaging-24.0-py3-none-any.whl (53 kB)
Using cached pillow-10.3.0-cp312-cp312-macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl (3.5 MB)
Using cached pyparsing-3.1.2-py3-none-any.whl (103 kB)
Using cached python_dateutil-2.9.0.post0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (229 kB)
Using cached pytz-2024.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (505 kB)
Using cached tenacity-8.2.3-py3-none-any.whl (24 kB)
Using cached tzdata-2024.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (345 kB)
Installing collected packages: pytz, tzdata, tenacity, six, pyparsing, pillow, packaging, numpy, kiwisolver, graphviz, fonttools, cycler, scipy, python-dateutil, plotly, contourpy, pandas, matplotlib, catboost
Successfully installed catboost-1.2.5 contourpy-1.2.1 cycler-0.12.1 fonttools-4.51.0 graphviz-0.20.3 kiwisolver-1.4.5 matplotlib-3.8.4 numpy-1.26.4 packaging-24.0 pandas-2.2.2 pillow-10.3.0 plotly-5.21.0 pyparsing-3.1.2 python-dateutil-2.9.0.post0 pytz-2024.1 scipy-1.13.0 six-1.16.0 tenacity-8.2.3 tzdata-2024.1

real    1m38.142s
user    0m37.879s
sys     0m18.653s
$
$
$ python -c 'import catboost'
$

